# Django - Signals on M2M

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm making an app to manage equipment loans at a school. the system has the following functions. you have a loan form which shows me the equipment that is available and the person selects who wants to take once save the form the state of these computers move from being "Available" to "Busy" of the classI ManyToManyField have a loan which you can see signs deal with but I am unclear how it works. my app data are:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed

class Estado_Equipo(models.Model):
  nombre_estado_equipo=models.CharField(max_length=30)  

def __unicode__(self):
    mostrar  = "%s"%(self.nombre_estado_equipo)
    return mostrar  


class Equipos(models.Model):
 nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 tipo_equipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Equipo) 
 descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=50)
 marca = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 modelo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 serial = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
 estado_equipo = models.ForeignKey(Estado_Equipo)
 fecha_compra = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    mostrar  = "%s "%(self.nombre)
    return mostrar

BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Activo'),(False, 'Finalizado'))

class Prestamo(models.Model):
 id_persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
 fecha_solicitud = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
 fecha_prestamo = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False)
 fecha_entrega = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True, auto_now_add = False)
 salon = models.ForeignKey(Salon,null=True,blank=True)
 equipos = models.ManyToManyField(Equipos)
 estado_prestamo = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
 observaciones = models.TextField(verbose_name='observaciones sobre el prestamo',null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    mostrar = "%s - %s - %s "%(self.fecha_solicitud, self.fecha_prestamo, self.fecha_entrega)
    return mostrar
```

Comment: Have you read about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed